# How to query a SQL database using C# based on a foreign key match

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

I have the following entity classes for my database:

```
[Table("Results")]
    public class ResultsEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ComponentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ComponentId")]
        public ComponentEntity Component { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Units { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Components")]
    public class ComponentEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string IconCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to query my Results table and get the result information plus the ComponentEntity Title (from the Components table). They are connected through the foreign key of the `ComponentId` Guid. This is my first time querying a SQL database with C# and I am struggling to find the correct syntax. My attempt so far is as follows:

```
IQueryable<ResultsEntity> resultQuery =
                from results in _dbContext.Results
                select results;


            foreach (ResultsEntity result in resultQuery)
            {
                var resultData = new ResultData
                {
                    Id = result.Id,
                    Status = result.Status,
                    Primary = result.Value,
                    Units = result.Units,
                    // How can I get the title of the component here? 
                };
            }
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
_dbContext.Results.Include(e => e.Component).Select(item =>
        new ResultData
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Status = item.Status,
                Primary = item.Value,
                Units = item.Units,
                Title = item.Component.Title
            };);
```

You include Component here to fill it with your values from DB. After it you can use your Component field in ResultsEntity to get necessary values.

Answer (score 1):

You can join it by using the following linq query

```
from results in _dbContext.Results
            .Include(r => r.ComponentEntity)
        select results;
```